# Move data in a table present in 2000+ .docx files to a single .xlsx file (2010)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, conversion, data-transfer

I receive 40+ emails per week each with a word doc attached. The word documents are in the same semantic format but carry unique client data authorizing services. I only need a portion of the data found in the .docx. The data I require occurs in the second table in the .docx and always at the same point, but the string length can vary.
I need to automatically move the data from the attached .docx to a single .xlsx file so I can upload it to another system.

So far, I can batch save the attachments to a folder. I can manually save the data from a designated point (ln30) onwards using Excel's Import txt.

As I have a backlog of 2000 of these, I'd like to automate the process of moving the relevant data from all the .docx to one .xlsx

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'd recommend using a rule in outlook that calls some VBA that does what you want.\

Answer (score 0):

Open a new Word document and click on the "Insert" Tab.
Click the down arrow next to "Object" and select "Text From File".
Add all the other files.
You now have a single consolidated Word File.
Save as a txt file.

Open Excel and go to the "Data" Tab.
Select "From text".
Open the text file you just saved.
Adjust the delimiters etc to your needs.

You should now have a long Excel file with all the Word Doc contents which you can sort or filter as needed.

Its not automated but it takes care of the backlog.